# Assembly added to the installer but still not work

Tags: c#, .net, installation, windows-installer

our C# application has a thirdparty C++ exe which requires Microsoft_VC90_CRT assembly. I have add that assembly in my msi installer which is built by using VS2008. It looks like that assembly is still not available to our application.

Is there any special step I need to do when I build my installer? or it is the wrong version of the assembly?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer without knowing more.  Make sure you understand .NET bitness,  Manifests, WinSXS and be sure to use [Depends](http://www.dependencywalker.com/)  to answer the question of whether an EXE or DLL can resolve it's (unmanaged) dependencies.